# MVC How To Create List from Rows in Table in DBContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, html.dropdownlistfor

I am relatively new to MVC, and I'm a little stuck....

I have 2 Models:

The Site model -

```
SiteID() As Integer
Name() As String
Latitude() As Double
Longitude() As Double
```

And the Device model -

```
DeviceID() As Integer
Make() As String
Model() As String
Serial() As String
Site() As Site
```

As you can see, a Device is linked to a Site.  What I'm trying to do is in the Device views for Create and Edit, make it so the Site field is a `DropDownListFor`, whose list contains the Sites that exist in the Site table.

So this is what I put in the View for creating the list that will be in the drop down:

```
@ModelType TestWebApplication2.Device
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Create"

    Dim selectSite As List(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim listOfSites As IEnumerable(Of TestWebApplication2.Site)

    For Each item In listOfSites
        selectSite.Add(New SelectListItem() With {.Value = item.SiteID, .Text = item.Name})
    Next

End Code
```

The problem is, in the line

> For Each item In listOfSites

I get a green squiggly under `listOfSites`, and it says "Variable 'listOfSites' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime."

I can see my tables in the context just fine:

[image: Application DB Context]

And I was guessing it should be done this way since `IEnumerable(Of TestWebApplication2.Site)` is the model type for the Index view, which can loop through `For Each` just fine.

So what am I missing regarding the listOfSites??

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you declare listOfSites as:

`Dim listOfSites As IEnumerable(Of TestWebApplication2.Site)`

without using `New` but another issue is that you don't seem to populate `listOfSites` before using it either!

By the way, you cannot instantiate your `listOfSites` as it stands because `IEnumerable(Of T)` is an interface, not an object.

You should perhaps populate your objects within a `Controller` and return a `View()` with your data.

To quickly create a controller and associated views:

1. Right click the controllers folder within your solution;
2. Add -> Controller...
3. Select Controller with views, using Entity Framework
4. Select the appropriate model and data context

This will add everything for you - enough to get you started at least!

Comment: OK.  Then what should my code look like in order to do that?

Comment: Well I already had the Controller with Views.  So I commented out the stuff in the View's Code section, and in the DevicesController this is now my Create:
        ' GET: Devices/Create
        Function Create() As ActionResult
            Dim listOfSites = (From site In db.Sites Select site.Name).ToList()
            Return View(listOfSites)
        End Function
But then in the View it says "listOfSites is not declared."

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some more playing around, I got it.

I did not have to do anything in the Controllers.

This is what the code in the Code section of the Device's Create view looks like now:

```
@ModelType TestWebApplication2.Device
@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Create"

    Dim selectSite As New List(Of SelectListItem)
    Dim db = New TestWebApplication2.Models.TestWebApplication2Context
    Dim listOfSites As List(Of Site)
    listOfSites = (From site In db.Sites Select site).ToList()

    For Each item In listOfSites
        selectSite.Add(New SelectListItem() With {.Value = item.SiteID, .Text = item.Name})
    Next

End Code
```

And the `DropDownListFor` is using `selectSite` as the source of items in it.

That works now.  The only thing is a bit of quirkiness with how the views look....but that should be a separate question if I can't figure that out.

Thank you, @Ric, for the clue regarding populating `listOfSites`.